# Execute a shell function from python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, sh

I'm trying to kill a specific process with a command which works well in the shell but not from python subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["kill", "$(ps | grep process | awk '{ print $1}' | head -n1)"], shell=False)
```

A work around would be to put this command into a shell script and run the shell script.
Is it possible from python subprocess directly ?

Comment: Use `shell=True`?

Comment: `kill $(ps | grep process | awk '{ print $1}' | head -n1)"` use `pkill process`?

Comment: what do you mean by shell script?

Comment: @KamilCuk I cannot use pkill as not available in the yocto distribution I have

Comment: @mousetrail I tried with shell True and it was not working better

Comment: @HoneyPoop put the command in kill.sh and execute kill.sh from subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("kill $(ps | grep ncat | awk '{print $1}' | head -n1)", shell=True)
```

In your example, you don't create a subprocess from bash, but at the same time you use $(...) which is a bash instruction. To be more precise, you create a `kill` process and pass it argument `$(...)` which is not precomputed.

The above example creates a bash process, and then tells it to interpret `kill $(...)`. Bash converts `$(...)` to a value, and then it runs `kill VALUE`.

Comment: Yes, only one "but", but `/bin/sh` is not necessarily bash. It may be other Bourne shell.